# Unexpected value meet parsing preserveAspectRatio attribute

Tags: svg, raphael

Building some maps with RaphelJS and keep seeing this error in the console in Firefox:

> Unexpected value meet parsing preserveAspectRatio attribute.

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio), at least, `meet` is a perfectly valid value for `preserveAspectRatio`.  Also, I'm not setting this, so it must be Raphel's doing.  Any guesses as to what's causing it?

It's not keeping things from functioning at the moment, but I'd prefer to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of preserveAspectRatio is

```
Attribute preserveAspectRatio="[defer] <align> [<meetOrSlice>]"
```

So a valid value for `<align>` is required before the optional `<meetOrSlice>` value `meet` RaphaelJS is setting preserveAspectRatio="meet" hence the Firefox warning.

Comment: It is solved in this issue: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/commit/b8a34e5642994665fd482b5ddde403cf31d90a56 Download the last version.